# How to avoid section extension with using balign in GNU as?

Tags: assembly, avr, gnu-assembler

I found that if I use the .balign directive to align the location counter to an n bit address boundary then there are padding bytes inserted *not* only where the directive is used. Unexpectedly the assembler also pads the section end such that the last address in the section is also at an n bit address boundary. This can be pretty wasteful if n is large. For instance

```
.section .test,"ax",@progbits
.balign  1024
nop
```

creates a 1024 bytes long section even though the nop instruction takes only a few bytes (2 in my case, I'm on AVR32 now).

Why is this, and how can I avoid it (such that the example is 2 bytes long, aligned at an address dividable by 1024)?

Comment: Seems to be avr specific, the x86 version works as expected.

Comment: Using an alignment directive in a segment also changes the alignment of the section. Otherwise the alignment directive wouldn't work. That's not the direct cause of your problem, but it might be related.